# what is the reverse formula of $price_with_tax = price_without_tax + (price_without_tax * (price_tax_rate / 100))

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to get the price_with_tax base on the given price without tax and tax rate on javascript and it works using the formula i mentioned.now I want to get the price_without_tax given the price_with_tax and tax_rate. I did it with

```
price_wo_tax = price_w_tax - (price_w_tax * (price_tax_rate / 100));
```

but our formula seems to be wrong? anyone who knows the reverse formula?

Comment: That's not a programming question. This is a mathematical question. If you have `price_without_tax`  why you need to calculate it again?

Comment: it is im working on javascript right now. i know it mathematical but its part of programming right?

Comment: This is grammar school algebra.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse your formula, you can get following:

```
price_wo_tax = (100 * price_w_tax) / (100 + price_tax_rate);
```

---

Here's explanation:

```
price_w_tax = price_wo_tax + (price_wo_tax * (price_tax_rate / 100))
```

transforms to

```
price_w_tax = price_wo_tax * (1 + price_tax_rate / 100))
```

transforms to

```
price_w_tax / (1 + price_tax_rate / 100)) = price_wo_tax
```

transforms to

```
price_wo_tax = 100 * price_w_tax / (100 + price_tax_rate)
```

Comment: thanks but i already got the answer from a friend its price_wo_tax = price_w_tax / ((price_tax_rate / 100) + 1);

Answer (score -1):

If your taxrate is say x%, and your total amount is $y.

```
GST = y - y/(1+x/100)
```

Of course, if your taxrate is not in percent but is a fraction between 0 and 1, the formula gets

```
GST = y - y/(1+x)
```

Comment: it not working. I have i have a price without tax of value 5 and i have tax rate of 50 and the result is 7.5 price with tax. now the given is 7.5 price with tax and i have 50 tax rate how will i get the price without tax? your formula didnt work sorry:(